# How long does installation take?

Tags: system-installation

Ubuntu is installing. I just see a spinning thing over the "Install" window that has left and right arrows to scroll through different windows. Is it hung up or proceeding as it should?

Comment: It depends on many variables that you have not defined in your question. What version of Ubuntu, what kind of PC, what kind of USB port, what kind of mass storage device, etc.  Some Debian test installs I did yesterday on old PCs retrofitted with SSDs took about 15 minutes at a guess, I wasn't timing them.

Comment: Full install to flash drive has taken me 45 min to an hour. I may not do that anymore as my new external SSD is almost as fast as it was when an internal drive and using grub2 loopmount, so ISO is in RAM with toram parameter. So from RAM to NVMe SSD is under 12 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

What you described looks like normal behavior for last stage of installation process.

I agree with other answer that on computers with SSD drive it may last up to 15 minutes so be patient.